# JPA resources for test and production

Tags: eclipse, maven, jpa

I have two persistence files very typical for maven based projects.

- src/main/resources/persistence.xml   (JNDI)
- src/test/resources/persistence.xml   (LOCAL_RESOURCE)

Both eclipse and maven fails to provide that to junit at test runtime failing my tests.

Comment: It's supposed to be under META-INF, not at the root.

Comment: It might not be Eclipse that's failing. Someone else reported that tests fired with maven-failsafe-plugin don't put `target/test-classes` in the classpath ahead of `target/classes` as it should to override the `META-INF/persistence.xml` (btw, it should be in META-INF, not resources root). I run tests with maven-surefire-plugin and the correct `persistence.xml` is loaded.

Comment: How do you load your persistence.xml file ? Via classpath?

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, try forcing the copy with [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
              <resources>          
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/**/*.xml/directory>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>              
            </configuration>            
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

While as I explained in the comment, I believe the problem is in the maven plugin. Try using `maven-surefire-plugin` instead of `maven-failsafe-plugin` if that's possible for you. But even if you get it to work with a second `persistence.xml` you will run into a different problem when it comes to maintenance (at least with Hibernate 5.2). It will not detect annotated classes from the main sources, but only from the test and you would have to list them with `<class>` tags and try not to forget to do it every time. The solution I found that works for me is to only have the main xml and instantiate my `EntityManagerFactory` like this:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void initJpa() throws Exception {
    TreeMap<String, Object> props = new TreeMap<>();
    props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/projectdb");
    props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "testuser");
    props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "testpass");
    props.put("javax.persistence.nonJtaDataSource", null); // important to override the data-source!
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistance.unit.name", props);
}
```

The `javax.persistence.nonJtaDataSource` property is what did the trick in the end.

This should bypass the classloading override problem you're experiencing.